# Need help on a JOIN query that almost works

Tags: mysql

I have four tables.

```
posts
| id      | title     |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | hello     |
| 2       | goodbye   |
+---------+-----------+

posts_tags
| tag_id  | post_id   |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 1         |
| 2       | 1         |
| 2       | 2         |
+---------+-----------+

comments
| id      | post_id    | comment   |
+---------+------------+-----------+
| 1       | 1          | hey       |
| 2       | 2          | what up   |
| 3       | 2          | blah      |
+---------+------------+-----------+

tags
| id      | name      |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | news      |
| 2       | photos    |
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to be able to select the posts, but have this as a result

```
post.id    post.title    tags              comments
-----------------------------------------------------
1          hello         news,photos       1
2          goodbye       photos            2
```

Something like

```
SELECT *,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) AS tags,
       COUNT(comments.id) AS comments
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN comments
        ON posts.id = comments.post_id
    LEFT JOIN posts_tags
        ON posts.id = posts_tags.post_id
    LEFT JOIN tags
        ON posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY posts.id
```

The problem I'm running into is it's not returning the proper count of comments.  Instead, it seems to be returning the number of tags. Please advise, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try COUNT(distinct comments.id)